# Html audio tag to preload entire stream

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, soundcloud

Is there a way to preload entire mp3 in html audio tag.

I'm having this problem for a long time. I have soundcloud player that uses html audio tag, im setting the audio source, the audio starts playing and the buffering starts.

The problem is that, soundcloud audio source is protected with short life token, when audio pre-buffer more data, buffering stops, when audio wants to continue reading the stream, it gets 404 from soundcloud and can't resume buffering.

I've noticed that if i pause the audio, whole track will be loaded at once, but this is not a solution that i need.

Comment: Hey, could you provide an example via jsbin, jsfiddle or similiar? What do you mean "buffering stops"? How do you achieve that? Thanks

Comment: here is my web app and direct link to a long mix: http://mycloudplayers.com/?play=137600832

it's not happening all the time, but it happens a lot (even on short tracks), you'll see the buffered indicator, if the audio prebuffer enough data, it will stop until the current position is near buffered.
@gryzzly are you from soundcloud devs? i expected someone from soundcloud to respond to this, i think there is no way to prebuffer whole stream without flash (or another plugin).

Comment: in order for me to help you I'd need a code example reduced only to audio object and soundcloud source not buffering, your site might containt any number of other scripts that might break the buffering. it'd also help you to find out the problem, cheers

Comment: here is a sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/c3XnG/1/

Comment: thanks! any more details when it stops buffering, what browsers? it buffers fine for me

Comment: i experienced this mostly on chrome. right now it happened on trackId=125751996 just change it in the src. as i can see, it doesn't need to be a long audio. you can check the src, it redirects to smth like: https://soundcloud.hs.llnwd.net/eT0I5S6vXVQt.128.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1393856589&Signature=vZK3D%2B84%2FjLiazEFI1K0HritO10%3D&e=1393856589&h=06c7754ee14951b6ef13702bd455314d and this link doesn't last for long

Comment: did it start happening at particular time?

Comment: it happens at random time on random sources. i can't find any way to reporoduce this all the time. even more, on pause, the audio element continue buffering whole stream. this is actually what i want but when audio is playing.

Comment: is it possibly related to your internet connection? streams expire after 2xtimes the track's length, so there'd be a very long pause in buffering for the stream to expire

Comment: if you're 100% sure about expiration, i'll create another simple test with more tracks queued, and printing the log.

Comment: i started to keep the log for audioElement.onError. i'll keep you updated if i have more info.

Comment: here is another simple playlist player, with error logger: http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9QN/ 
on error it will log the error and go to next track. you can leave it in background and check it after some time.

Comment: i updated the code, i've had a small bug: http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9QN/1/

Comment: it happened on jsfiddle on 7th track for me (win/chrome)
http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9QN/2/ you can skip the track near the end if the track is too long

Comment: @gryzzly that's all? no more ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `<audio preload="auto"`?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp, you should set **preload="auto"**.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers behave differently. Chrome buffers whole track on pause (for whatever reason). preload=auto does not do much but fills the buffer from the time url is set rather than on play event.
Flash is different. It loads whole track anyway. But it can not seek to unbuffered position because it can not do byte range requests. And it also wastes your and our bandwidth.

Comment: If you want to take control on the buffering process take a look into Media Source Extensions. You can download whole media by pieces in several threads for example, store it locally if you want.